# Value stored to seconds during its initialization is never read

Tags: iphone

```
float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;
if ((seconds = 11)){
   [self performSelector:@selector(viewController) withObject:nil]; 
} else {
    if ((seconds = 23)){
        [self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil];  
    } else {
}
```

Anyidea how to fix this message in blue when i just want to see if audioplayer current playback time  is 11 then do this or 23 then do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably late and you only need a second pair of eyes, happens all the time :) Try this:

```
float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;

if ((seconds == 11.0)){

   [self performSelector:@selector(viewController) withObject:nil]; 

    } else {

if ((seconds == 23.0)){
    [self performSelector:@selector(secondViewController) withObject:nil];  


} else {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
float seconds = audioPlayer.currentTime;

if (seconds == 11.0) {
    // Do something
} else if (seconds == 23.0) {
    // Do something else
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: i spent my todays vote quota, otherwise you deserve +1 for not only answering but also improving the code :)

Comment: +1 for not only answering but also improving the code, hehe :)

Comment: past midnight UTC, so here it goes... :)